# symfony htaccess 2 sites

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I have 1 site with the following directory structure:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\site1\web\app.php
```

and htaccess file which is located in C:\xampp\htdocs with the following contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Change below before deploying to production
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site1/web/app.php [QSA,L] //note the line here
</IfModule>
```

so when I hit localhost in my browser I get directly to app.php. Now I need to add a second site to the following directory:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\site2\web\app.php
```

so when I hit

```
localhost/site2
```

I get directly to my site2 app.php. I created .htaccess in

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\site2
```

folder and removed old htaccess from C:\xampp\htdocs. I tried to change the folder in my new htacess from

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site1/web/app.php [QSA,L]
```

to simply

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app.php [QSA,L]
```

and some other things but neither of them worked. Any ideas how to fix the issue would be welcome. I did not create virtual hosts or other stuff like that. Thank you.

Comment: look into `RewriteBase`

Comment: could you please provide any example? Thank you

Comment: `RewriteBase /site1/`

Comment: Ok, i`ll try that, thank you

Comment: Unfortunately the solution with RewriteBase is not working